# Android: animation best practice

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

I am creating this demo game for learning purposes.
in my game, objects are falling from the sky every couple of seconds

in my MainGameView (which extends View of course) 
I have an ArrayList of "Objects Falling from the sky".
now, I am using the onDraw method to draw my game.

my question is:
should I create a new thread for every "falling object" in order to update its position?
I want to know what is the best practice in animation and multi-threading in android

thanks

Comment: Look into AndEngine http://www.andengine.org/

Comment: hey, I want to create something independent and not using 3rd party frameworks.
what is the built-in, best-practice solution for android animations?